# Angular filter and binding (ngModelChange)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on the hotel project. I have a reservation screen. Here I ask the hotel name, region name, check-in and check-out dates, the number of adults and children. When the necessary information is entered, when I press the search button, I filter according to the values ​​there. I connected the date filter with html using the (NgModelChange) method, but I couldn't connect the html with the hotel and region methods correctly. I made a filter as an experiment, but I got the wrong result. I don't know where I'm making a mistake. How can I fix this?

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Which Hotel?</label>
    <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="name" formControlName="name" (change)="changeHotel()" />
    <mat-autocomplete #name="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let hotel of filteredHotels | async" [value]="hotel">
            {{hotel}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
&nbsp;
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Which Region?</label>
    <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="region" formControlName="region" (change)="changeRegion()" />
    <mat-autocomplete #region="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let region of filteredRegions | async" [value]="region">
            {{region}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
&nbsp;
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Entry Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="mdpStartDate" formControlName="startDate" (ngModelChange)="changeDate()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mdpStartDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #mdpStartDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
&nbsp;
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Pay Date?</label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="mdpEndDate" formControlName="endDate" (ngModelChange)="changeDate()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mdpEndDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #mdpEndDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Adult Number?</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" matInput formControlName="adult" (ngModelChange)="filterAge()">
</mat-form-field>
&nbsp;
<mat-form-field>
    <label>Chd Number?</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="3" value="0" matInput formControlName="chd" (ngModelChange)="filterAge()">
</mat-form-field>
&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="search()">Search</button>
```

.ts

```
 form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    region: new FormControl(''),
    adult: new FormControl(1),
    chd: new FormControl(0),
    startDate: new FormControl(),
    endDate: new FormControl(),
});

filtered: any[];
showList = false;
name = '';
regions: string[];
hotels: Hotel[] = [];

filteredHotels: Observable<string[]>;
filteredRegions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {

    this.regions = this.hotels.reduce((arr: string[], current) => {
        if (!arr.includes(current.regionName)) {
            arr.push(current.regionName);
        }
        return arr;
    }, []);


    this.filteredHotels = this.form.get("name").valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(v => {
                return this.filterHotels(v)
            })
        );

    this.filteredRegions = this.form.get("region").valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(value => this.filterRegions(value).map(h => h.regionName))
        );

    this.form.get("adult").valueChanges.
        subscribe(v => {
            this.adult = new Array(v).map(e => new Object)
        });

    this.form.get("chd").valueChanges
        .subscribe(v => {
            this.children = new Array(v).map(e => new Object)
        });


    this.hotelservice.getHotels().subscribe(
        data => {
            this.hotels = data;
            this.dsHotels.data = data;
            this.dsHotels.paginator = this.paginator;
        },
        err => {
            console.error("Hata oluştu: ", err);
        }
    );
}

private filterHotels(value: string): string[] {
    const name = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.hotels
        .map(x => x.hotelName)
        .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(name));
}

private filterRegions(value: string): Hotel[] {
    const region = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.hotels
        .filter(hotel => hotel.regionName.toLowerCase().includes(region));
}


private isEqual(date1: Date, date2: Date) {
    return date1.getDate() == date2.getDate() && date1.getMonth() == date2.getMonth() && date1.getFullYear() == date2.getFullYear();
}


private isDataEqualToDate(value1: any, date2: Date) {
    if (value1 == null) return true;
    return this.isEqual(new Date(value1), date2);
}

private getFilteredDate(): Hotel[] {
    return this.hotels.filter(
        x => this.isDataEqualToDate(this.form.get("startDate").value, new Date(x.checkInDate))
            && this.isDataEqualToDate(this.form.get("endDate").value, new Date(x.payDate))
    );
}

changeHotel() {
    this.dsHotels.data = this.filterHotels("value");
}

changeRegion() {
    this.dsHotels.data = this.filterRegions("value");
}

changeDate() {
    this.dsHotels.data = this.getFilteredDate();
}


filterAge() {
    //this.dsHotels.data = this.hotels.filter(x => x.numberOfAd == this.form.get("adult").value && x.numberOfChd == this.form.get("chd").value);
    this.dsHotels.data = this.hotels.filter(x => x.numberOfAd == x.numberOfChd);
}

search() {
    this.showList = true;
    this.filterHotels("");
    this.filterRegions("");
    this.changeDate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you created your form with [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) you can switch from event binding in template

```
< ... (change)="changeHotel()" 
< ... (ngModelChange)="changeDate()">
```

to do it inside class.

```
ngOnInit() {
  // ... initial logic
  this.form.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(this.changeHotel.bind(this))
  this.form.get('region').valueChanges.subscribe(this.changeRegion.bind(this))
  this.form.get('startDate').valueChanges.subscribe(this.changeDate.bind(this))
  this.form.get('endDate').valueChanges.subscribe(this.changeDate.bind(this))
  this.form.get('adult').valueChanges.subscribe(this.filterAge.bind(this))
  this.form.get('chd').valueChanges.subscribe(this.filterAge.bind(this))
}
```

> Reactive form instances like FormGroup and FormControl have a
>   valueChanges method that returns an observable that emits the latest
>   values. You can therefore subscribe to valueChanges to update instance
>   variables or perform operations.

[source](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/)